# How do I configure multiple connection factories in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have two domains which I access though two application interfaces `IA1`, `IA2`, they each use different repositories `R1` and `R2`. The repositories use an interface that lets them create NHibernate sessions, `ISimpleSessionFactory`.

If the repositories shared a database I would set them both up like this using a unity container:

```
var unity = new UnityContainer();

unity.RegisterType<ISimpleSessionFactory, NHibernateSessionFactory>(
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionA"));

unity.RegisterType<IA1, A1>();
unity.RegisterType<R1>();

unity.RegisterType<IA2, A2>();
unity.RegisterType<R2>();
```

But they don't share a connection string, so I want to do something like this:

```
var unity = new UnityContainer();

var child1 = unity.CreateChildContainer();

child1.RegisterType<ISimpleSessionFactory, NHibernateSessionFactory>(
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionA"));

child1.RegisterType<IA1, A1>();
child1.RegisterType<R1>();

var child2 = unity.CreateChildContainer();

child2.RegisterType<ISimpleSessionFactory, NHibernateSessionFactory>(
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionB"));

child2.RegisterType<IA2, A2>();
child2.RegisterType<R2>();
```

My problem however is that I want to resolve `IA2` from `A1` class. Ideally I want to have everything but the session factories in the parent container. It's just the repositories `R1` and `R2` that need different `ISimpleSessionFactory`s but as I understand it it will only ever fall back to parent if not resolved locally in child, so if I move anything to the parent it won't find the session factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, I believe you could just employ named registrations with no need for two separate interfaces:

```
  // first named registration
  child1.RegisterType<ISimpleSessionFactory, NHibernateSessionFactory>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
            new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionA"), "ConnectionA");

  child1.RegisterType<IA1, A1>( new InjectionConstructor( new ResolvedParameter<ISimpleSessionFactory>("ConnectionA"));
  child1.RegisterType<R1>( new InjectionConstructor( new ResolvedParameter<ISimpleSessionFactory>("ConnectionA") );

  // the same goes for the second one, just create a named registration 
  // under a different name
```

The trick here is to register `IA1` and `R1` (and `IA2`/`R2` respectively) in a way so that you precisely point how the parameter should be resolved (`ResolvedParameter` pointing to a named registration).

Note that the `InjectionConstructor` could not be usable if your services' constructors have more parameters. In such case, use `InjectionFactories` instead

```
  child1.RegisterType<IA1, A1>( 
     new InjectionFactory( container => 
         {
             // arbitrarily complicated imperative code to create an instance
             // first resolve ISimpleSessionFactory by name

             ISimpleSessionFactory factory = 
                container.Resolve<ISimpleSessionFactory>( "ContainerA" );

             // then create A1

             return new A1( factory, any, other, parameters, here );
         }
     ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Until I hear a better answer I am doing this, defining separate interfaces for the two session factories so they can both be registered in the same container.

```
interface IASessionFactory : ISimpleSessionFactory{}
interface IBSessionFactory : ISimpleSessionFactory{}

class ASessionFactory : NHibernateSessionFactory, IASessionFactory{...}
class BSessionFactory : NHibernateSessionFactory, IBSessionFactory{...}

var unity = new UnityContainer();

unity.RegisterType<IASessionFactory, ASessionFactory>(
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionA"));

unity.RegisterType<IBSessionFactory, BSessionFactory>(
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("ConnectionB"));

unity.RegisterType<IA1, A1>();
unity.RegisterType<R1>();

unity.RegisterType<IA2, A2>();
unity.RegisterType<R2>();
```

`R1` and `R2` must then use `IASessionFactory` and `IBSessionFactory`, not `ISimpleSessionFactory`.